# Is there a notation for a JSON type in a JSON string

Tags: json

I am thinking about using JSON as a way to communicate information inside my programm in a way suggested in [this talk](http://vimeo.com/79866979).

As i read the [JavaScript Object Notation](http://json.org/json-de.html) i see no way of noting my objecttype.

Suppose i communicate the string `{ "val" : 5 }`, how would i know what that string was for.

I would like to send the string `error = { "val" : 5 }` and `measurement = { "val" : 5 }`. but as i read it this would not be valid JSON notation.

Is the solution always something like `{ "type" : "error", "val" : 5 }` or am i missing some bigger concept in JavaScript Object Notation.

EDIT: ops - did not do JSON in my examples, fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    "type": "error",
    "val": 5
}
```

That's the proper way to format your JSON

If you have different type of values, then you will be able to have an array looking like this:

```
[
    {
        "type": "error",
        "val": 5
    },
    {
        "type": "measurement",
        "val": 45
    }
]
```

Comment: JSON is already a key-value pair system, what’s the point of the redundancy of having two pairs with a `type` key and a `value` key when `type: val` will do?

Answer (score 1):

In JSON (and Javascript in general), the key name identifies the type of the value. A JSON-like version of your examples:

```
{
  'error': 5,
  'measurement': 5
}
```